# C# Windows Mobile datagrid data

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, datagrid

I have a datagrid that has two columns.  The DataSource for the datagrid is "myTable" which is a DataTable.  All I am trying to do is add a row to the DataTable and have the new row be displayed in the datagrid.  Here is the simple code I wrote to add the item to the DataTable:

```
DataRow dRow = myTable.NewRow();
dRow.ItemArray.SetValue("test", 0);
dRow.ItemArray.SetValue("test1", 1);
```

What am I missing to make the new data row show in the datagrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NewRow() method doesn't add the row to the table, it only returns a row with the appropriate fields included in it.  You still need to add the row to the table.

```
myTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works without any issues - adding a row to the table is the step you were missing.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("a");
            dt.Columns.Add("b");
            dt.Rows.Add("aaa", "bbb");
            dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("111", "222");
        }
```